# Unable to add icon to sidebar in docusaurus

Tags: sidebar, docusaurus

My sidebar looks like

... items: [ { type: 'category', label: 'iOS', link: { ...

I want to add an svg file at the iOS level containing the Apple logo, within that string.

I tried adding link to svg image. But that didn't work

Answer (score 0):

You can define the type item as `html` to render a custom markup. Your sidebar item will seem like this:

```js
module.exports = {
  myHtmlSidebar: [
    {
      type: 'html',
      value: '<img src="sponsor.png" alt="Sponsor" />', // The HTML to be rendered
      defaultStyle: true, // Use the default menu item styling
    },
  ],
};
```

I figured out it on documentation about [sidebar items](https://docusaurus.io/docs/sidebar/items). For your case, refer about [HTML: render custom markup](https://docusaurus.io/docs/sidebar/items#sidebar-item-html).